# Search from list with dictionaries and sublists and create a new list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here I have a list of dictionaries with tshirts. I want to search in the dictionaries for "blue" shirts and create a list with the brands that they have this color. My code returns an empty list.

```
tshirts=[

{'brand': 'A',
'color': ['blue', 'white', 'black'],
'size': ['XS', 'M', 'L']},

{'brand': 'B',
'color': ['blue', 'red', 'black'],
'size': ['S', 'M', 'L']},

{'brand': 'C',
'color': ['blue', 'white', 'yellow'],
'size': ['S', 'M', 'XL']}

]


brands=[]

def search(attribute, value):
    for d in tshirts:
        if d[attribute] == value:
            brands.append(d['brand'])

    print(brands)
    
search('color', 'blue')
```

Comment: `['blue', 'white', 'black'] != 'blue'`, your logic doesn't account for the fact that the attribute you're filtering by is a list.

Comment: As @jonrsharep suggested you are comparing string to list
try `if value in d[attribute]  :`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
brands=[i['brand'] for i in tshirts if 'blue' in i['color']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look if the value is inside the list, not if it is equal to it. Also, using a global `brands` variable will give you problems, keep it inside the function and return the list of brands.

```py
tshirts = [
    {
        'brand': 'A',
        'color': ['blue', 'white', 'black'],
        'size': ['XS', 'M', 'L'],
    },
    {
        'brand': 'B',
        'color': ['blue', 'red', 'black'],
        'size': ['S', 'M', 'L'],
    },
    {
        'brand': 'C',
        'color': ['blue', 'white', 'yellow'],
        'size': ['S', 'M', 'XL'],
    },
]


def search(attribute, value):
    brands = []
    for d in tshirts:
        if value in d[attribute]:
            brands.append(d['brand'])
    return brands


print(search('color', 'blue'))  # ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

You could also do this with a list comprehension:

```py
def search(attribute, value):
    return [d['brand'] for d in tshirts if value in d[attribute]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brands = []
def search(attribute, value):
    for d in tshirts:
        if value in d[attribute] :
            brands.append(d['brand'])
    print(brands)

search('color', 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an generator.  A generator works like a list comprehension with the exception that it does not load results in memory.  Instead it allows you to iterate the results like a IQueryable in c#.  The search function returns iterable.

```
 tshirts=[
 {'brand': 'A','color': ['blue', 'white', 'black'],'size': ['XS', 'M', 'L']},
 {'brand': 'B','color': ['blue', 'red', 'black'],'size': ['S', 'M', 'L']},
 {'brand': 'C','color': ['blue', 'white', 'yellow'], 'size': ['S', 'M', 'XL']}
 ]

 def search(color):
     for item in tshirts:
         print(item['color'])
         if color in item['color']:
             yield item
    
 for item in search("blue"):
    print(item)

 or
 
 print (next(item))
```

output:

```
{'brand': 'A', 'color': ['blue', 'white', 'black'], 'size': ['XS', 'M', 'L']}
{'brand': 'B', 'color': ['blue', 'red', 'black'], 'size': ['S', 'M', 'L']}
{'brand': 'C', 'color': ['blue', 'white', 'yellow'], 'size': ['S', 'M', 'XL']}
```